# How to give Three.js objects a z-index without setting their z-coordinate?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 2d, z-index

I'm using Three.js to render a number of 2D objects (`THREE.PlaneGeometry`) arranged in layers. All of them should be aligned on the same flat plane, but with some objects "in front of" or "blocking the view of" others. In other words, I want to simulate the CSS `z-index` property, but without actually using the `z`-dimension, because that would cause perspective issues.

Does Three.js have a facility for this?

Comment: if you set z-dimension and then use a ortographic camera?

Comment: @Ale_32: This *would* be a solution, but there are other reasons I need a perspective camera. The user will be able to move around in the 3D space, and the 2D canvas should look like a flat painting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use polygonOffset (http://threejs.org/docs/api/materials/Material.html)

Comment: Could you tell me *how* to use that property to achieve my goal? It's not clear from the documentation. (Even better, perhaps you could create a jsFiddle, based on stdob--'s fiddle in his answer.)

Comment: Update: I think I figured it out ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adt1d5b7/1/)), and it seems to work! If you elaborate a bit on your answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Your sample is correct. You need to use negative values to pull objects closer to the view. In my project I used negative values for both polygonOffsetFactor and polygonOffsetUnit properties. Try to find opengl resources to know more about this technique.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the `renderOrder` of mesh, but `material.depthTest` should be `false` firstly.

```
    body.material.depthTest = false;
    body.renderOrder = 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

1) You can use `object.renderOrder`:

http://jsfiddle.net/adt1d5b7/

2) You can use ortographic camera and render 2D canvas to texture of 3D object:

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_rtt.html

3) Combine renderOrder and rendering to texture:

http://jsfiddle.net/mne9hgf8/

Comment: Nice fiddle. But it doesn't actually work if I rotate the camera a little bit. I'll actually see a 'blending' of all three squares, not one nicely in front of the other. But the `renderOrder` solution would be perfect if it worked.

Comment: Yes, that's why I mentioned the second option, which can be combined: render to texture.

Comment: I see. To be honest, that's pretty advanced, and seems a bit overkill for the problem I'm trying to solve. It feels like it might cause confusion in the future. (Although, if no other solutions are forthcoming, I may consider it.)